# Rmpi, OpenCPU, and Apparmor: DENIED request for "/"

Tags: r, mpi, openmpi, opencpu, apparmor

I have an R package that sends out a job to the OpenMPI cluster I have running by means of the Rmpi package.  All works as expected within an R session run from the console.  However, when I try to execute the relevant function with from my OpenCPU server like this (details changed to protect the innocent):

```
curl -XPOST http://99.999.999.99/ocpu/library/MyPackage/R/my_cluster_function
```

I get this error:

```
R call failed: process died.
```

(Other, non-cluster calling functions within the package work as expected via OpenCPU). I noticed in `/var/log/kern.log` a variety of requests being `DENIED` by apparmor, and I have been able to resolve most of them by adding entries into `/etc/apparmor.d/opencpu.d/custom` to allow OpenMPI to access the files it needs.  However, I cannot resolve these two issues (again, IP address changed) related to "open" requests for location `"/"`:

```
Oct 26 03:49:58 99.999.999.99 kernel: [142952.551234] type=1400 audit(1414295398.849:957): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="opencpu-main" name="/" pid=22486 comm="orted" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=33 ouid=0
Oct 26 03:49:58 99.999.999.99 kernel: [142952.556422] type=1400 audit(1414295398.857:958): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="opencpu-main" name="/" pid=22485 comm="apache2" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=33 ouid=0
```

Adding this to my apparmor rules did not help:

```
/* r,
```

Two questions:

1. Why is opencpu trying to read from my root level directory (or does this mean something else)?
2. More urgently, how can I resolve this apparmor issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a rule `/ r`? In apparmor, that is different from `/* r`.

Comment: Ah...that worked.  Thanks!  If you want to turn that into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add both apparmor rules

```
/ r,
/* r,
```

The first rule allows directory listing of `/` and the second rule allows read access to any file under `/`.

I don't understand why `Rmpi` wants to read `/` or why were you getting `process died` error instead of access denied. Are you sure the problem is completely resolved?

Comment: No it isn't, but there are no more apparmor denials in kernel.log so you addressed the question posed above :). I have narrowed the remaining problem down to communication with the other servers in the kernel, which I assume (based in part on tests with other logins on my server) is failing because the opencpu user does not have the necessary SSH credentials. I am looking into how to configure that, but feel free to push me in the right direction.

Comment: I have never used `mpi` so I'm not sure exactly what it does. Note that the OpenCPU cloud server forks the main R process which might cause trouble if R code relies on threading or open connections. If you get stuck please send an email on the opencpu mailing list with a small example and perhaps I can help debug.